# symfony router debuger shows strange <href=> prefix

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

All methods created in my controllers has `<href=>` prefix. Also I have strange behavior when sometimes some methods does not work depend on methods order in controller.

For example if *api_delete* is before *api_create* method then it works. When *api_delete* is after *api_create* , then does not work.

Any idea where comes `<href=>` from ?

```
Name                     Method  Scheme Host   Path                               

api_delete                 ANY     ANY  ANY   <href=>/api/delete/{id}            
api_create                 ANY     ANY  ANY   <href=>/api/create_ajax
fos_user_security_login  GET|POST  ANY  ANY   /login                             
fos_user_security_check   POST     ANY  ANY   /login_check
```

### Symfony 4 files

```
/**
 * @Route("api/delete/{id}", name="api_delete", options={"expose" = true})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Api $api
 * @return Response
 */
public function delete(Request $request, Api $api)
.
.
.
/**
 * @Route("/api/create_ajax", name="api_create", options={"expose" = true})
 * @param Request $request
 * @return RedirectResponse|Response
 */
public function create(Request $request)
```

config/routes.yaml

```
# config/routes.yaml
fos_user:
   resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

config/routes/annotations.yaml

```
# config/routes/annotations.yaml
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

config/routes/fos_js_routing.yaml

```
# config/routes/fos_js_routing.yaml
fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing-sf4.xml"
```

config/packages/routing.yaml

```
# config/packages/routing.yaml
framework:
    router:
        strict_requirements: ~
```

Comment: That controller where quoted actions "api_create" and "api_delete" are defined -- what is there before `class SomeController extends ...`? Is there any global `@Route()` annotation? Any annotations at all? If yes, can you add that part to question, please?

Comment: @Route("api/delete/{id}" should be @Route("/api/delete/{id}". Don't know if the missing slash is messing up things.